# The probability of an event using the conditional probability

Tags: probability

If A and B are two events such that:

$P(C|D) = \frac{1}{3}$ , $P(C|D') = \frac{1}{5}$ and $P(D) = \frac{1}{4}$

Find :

1) $P(C \cap D) $

2)$P(C\cap D') $

3) $P(C) $

My turn :

1)$ P(C \cap D) = P(C|D) \times P(D) = \frac{1}{3} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{12}$

2) $P(C \cap D') = P(C|D') \times P(D') =\frac{1}{5} \times \frac{3}{4} = \frac{3}{20}$

3) Now i dont know how can i get $P(C)$ using the information above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that $P(C) = P( C \cap D) + P(C \cap D') = P(C | D) P(D) + P(C | D') \Bigl(1-P(D)\Bigr)$